# django on IIS winserver 2016 wfastcgi handler line 791

Tags: python, django, iis, windows-server-2016

installed python 3.8.1 ,django 3.0.3 on windows server 2016 with wfastcgi and iam getting this error, cant find anything to fix it..

gave IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool read&use permissions on python installation folder but it still does not work, somehow the handler can`t read it, but as much as i know the config seems to be right. Hope you can help me. Thanks in regards.

C:\inetpub\wwwroot
-> web.conf

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="Python FastCGI"
                path="*"
                verb="*"
                modules="FastCgiModule"
                scriptProcessor="c:\users\administrator\python38\python.exe|c:\users\administrator\python38\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py"
                resourceType="Unspecified"
                requireAccess="Script" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>

    <appSettings>
        <!-- Required settings --> 
        <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="web.wsgi.application" />
        <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AddressLizenzbuch" />

        <!-- Optional settings -->

        <add key="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" value="web.settings" />

    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AddressLizenzbuch\web\blog\static
-> web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <!-- Overrides the FastCGI handler to let IIS serve the static files -->
        <handlers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

manage.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys


def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'web.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

ERROR

```
Error occurred while reading WSGI handler:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\administrator\python38\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 791, in main
    env, handler = read_wsgi_handler(response.physical_path)
  File "c:\users\administrator\python38\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 633, in read_wsgi_handler
    handler = get_wsgi_handler(os.getenv("WSGI_HANDLER"))
  File "c:\users\administrator\python38\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 603, in get_wsgi_handler
    handler = getattr(handler, name)
AttributeError: module 'web' has no attribute 'wsgi'


StdOut: 

StdErr:
```

[image]

Comment: try to put the python folder to the c drive like c:\python38\. at the time of the installation did you set the install for all users? set the iis_iusrs and iusr permission to the site folder and python folder. please refer this link for more detail:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/configure-web-apps-for-iis-windows?view=vs-2019

Comment: In your web browser (in the image) why are you navigating to `localhost/AddressLizenzbuch` instead of just `localhost`? I suggest double checking your the path to `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AddressLizenzbuch`. For example, on a terminal can you list the contents of that path? I think on a Windows CMD terminal the command would be `dir C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AddressLizenzbuch`

Comment: Typically, you wouldn't rename the outside project directory. You would have something like `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webproject\webproject\wsgi.py`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be an easy fix. Your Django project is the following structure

`C:/inetpub/wwwroot/AddressLizenzbuch/web/web` with `web.config`.

The problem is the extra directory `AddressLizenzbuch`. **REMOVE IT.**

[image]

Your directory should look like `C:/inetpub/wwwroot/web/web`.

The problem is that wfastcgi.py is looking for `C:/inetpub/wwwroot/AddressLizenzbuch/web/wsgi.py` but that path obviously doesn't exist. Your config file should include this line *after* you remove that non-essential directory `AddressLizenzbuch`

```
<add key="PYTHONPATH" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\web" />
```

To make this clear, your wsgi.py file should be located at `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\web\web\wsgi.py`

If you have any more questions, feel free to browse this project [webproject](https://github.com/Johnnyboycurtis/webproject) on GitHub